# json.net serialization error using custom objects

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, json.net

I am getting an error when calling asp.net mvc action method returning a JsonNetResult. using the following [code](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net) for that.

This is what I see in the response body. for some reason it is struggling with the < and > text.

```
{
    "archivedEmailsData":[
          {
            "Id":294455,
            "Date":"2009-09-10T15:20:00",
            "Subject":"Testing fix in 2.20.8.0 - quotes or single 'quote' and char < and="">"
          }]
}
```

original text of object
Subject "Testing fix in 2.20.8.0 - quotes or single 'quote' and char < and >"   string

using angularjs to make the call but I get the same thing when using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid and should look like the following:

```
{
    "archivedEmailsData": [
        {
            "Id": 294455,
            "Date": "2009-09-10T15:20:00",
            "Subject": "Testing fix in 2.20.8.0 - quotes or single 'quote' and char < and >"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why is it getting serialized improperly? Not sure if it something with the content type maybe or formatting setting.

Comment: This would depend on the source that is producing the json.

Comment: Did you try JsonMediatTypeFormatter to deserialize. It serializes object content rather than string content

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem was not with the serialization but with a custom ActionFilterAttribute.